Login Button Render Issue - React Native
Ok, I've got a minor, but seriously annoying, style issue with my Login button.
It's a TouchableOpacity element from the React Native library.
I don't know why but it's cutting off in the middle... I've tried a bunch of different styles like changing the lineHeight and adding padding etc... but it doesn't work. Tried removing it and re-adding it... didn't work.
It looks like this:

Here's the full code & style:
return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder="Email"
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            secureTextEntry
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TouchableOpacity
              onPress = {onPressLogin}
              style={styles.loginBtn}>
              <Text>Log in.</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {setShowRegisterForm(!showRegisterForm)}}
            style={styles.registerBtn}
            title='Register'
          />
        </View>
 </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputView:{
    width:"80%",
    backgroundColor:"#3AB4BA",
    borderRadius:25,
    height:50,
    marginBottom:20,
    justifyContent:"center",
    padding:20
  },
  loginBtn: {
    textAlign:'center',   
  },
});

I have to press in the upper half of the button for the button to function properly.
Please help fix.
Update
I've removed the TouchableOpacity entirely and replaced it instead with a button. However, the Opacity appears to be stuck in place and does not render the button. I've cleared the cache, even deleted my node_modules folder and did an npm install to reinstall all my dependencies but the issue persists. I'm running the project using expo start -clear. I'll show my code and screenshot below.
Template Code:
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder="Email"
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            secureTextEntry
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <Button
              onPress={() => {onPressLogin()}}
              title='Log In'
            />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {setShowRegisterForm(!showRegisterForm)}}
            style={styles.registerBtn}
            title='Register'
          />
        </View>
    </View>
    );

Again, the TouchableOpacity simply will not go away and the Button for 'Log In' does not render.


try this style
const CustomButton = () => {
  return (
    <View
    // style={styles.container}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        //  onPress = {onPressLogin}
        style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <View
          style={
            // styles.inputView
            {
              width: '80%',
              backgroundColor: '#3AB4BA',
              borderRadius: 25,
              // height:50,
              marginBottom: 20,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              paddingVertical: 12,
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
              alignItems: 'center',
            }
          }>
          <Text>Log in.</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};


After a little massaging, this worked. Thanks for your response. I chance width to width:85 and turned height on.
